# use will, would, shall or should appropriately

Tags: grammar

> **A.** Complete the sentences using a positive or negative form of *will*, *would*, *shall*, *should* and the correct form of the verb in brackets. Sometimes more than one answer is possible.
>
> - I find it astonishing that the old theater______ (demolish). It was such a beautiful building!

I have tried the below answers:
will be demolished

reason: *will* is used to indicate I believe something is true. And because *demolish* act on *the old theater* so I used passive.

> **B.** Complete the sentences using a verb from the list and *will*, *would*, *shall*, or *should*.

[list:] walk

> - Thanks for the offer of a lift, but to be honest, I ___ sooner ____.

I have tried the below answers:
would...walk

reason: *would sooner* is used to express future preference. So the sentence means: I prefer to walk than accept your offer.

Above questions are from `English File 4th edition Advanced Plus Student’s Book eBook`. When I test my answers, the book says it is wrong.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for telling which responses you've already considered. To get better answers, can you edit the question to also say why you're concerned about the choices you considered? I should say, the first sentence seems like it could have many right answers, as the instructions suggest.

Comment: You say "I've tried the below answers".  And your answers look plausible to me. Are you saying that your teacher (or textbook, or app) tells you that "will demolish" and "would sooner walk" are incorrect?

Comment: **will be demolished** is right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in what way you "test" your answer with an ebook, but if it accepts or gives only one right answer for a question that might have more than one right answer, then maybe the given answer is only one example of several possible ones.

- *I find it astonishing that the old theater **will be** demolished!* —This is perfectly valid. In this sentence the speaker has learned that there are real plans to demolish it in the future.
- *I find it astonishing that the old theater **would be** demolished!* —This is also valid. In this sentence, the plans to demolish the theater *might* be really planned, or *might* just be being discussed and imagined. Since we are given only this one sentence, there's no context to say whether "will" or "would" is the better choice.
- *shall*, *should*: These are also valid choices, but *shall* is rather archaic and unusual in modern use. It works as an old-fashioned version of *will*. Similarly, in this context at least, *should* works the same as *would*, and is not archaic, but a bit more formal.

---

- *Thanks for the offer of a lift, but to be honest, I **would** sooner **walk**.* This is valid and makes sense. **None of the other choices fit.** Why? This sentence talks about your preference, something you would *like* to do, and uses hypothetical language. In this context, *sooner* doesn't mean "more soon," but means "prefer to." You could use other words, but you would have to change other parts of the phrase:
- *Thanks for the offer of a lift, but **I will walk**.* This is certain.You couldn't use *will* in the example with *sooner*. Since *will* won't work, neither will its equivalent *shall*.
- *should*: Here substituting *should* for *would* makes the sentence sound even more archaic than in the first version. "I should sooner walk" is valid but outdated.

Comment: For A, I figured out the right answer is: I find it astonishing that the old theater should have been demolished. It was such a beautiful building!

You are right. will / would be demolished is valid. But you say there's no context, I don't agree with you. Because there is another sentence there: It was such a beautiful building! It use past tense, so it means the old theater doesn't exist anymore. Therefore, it should / will have been demolished, but not will / would been demolished.

For B, I agree with you. Thanks for the offer of a lift, but to be honest, I would sooner walk.

Comment: If you can justify should / will have been demolished isn't better than your answer, I will accept your answer as the answer.